# Make material UI drawer stay the same size, instead of resizing when content size changes

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I'm using Material UI with a drawer.

Inside the drawer, is a set of Collapsible lists.  When I expand the list, the list text items can be quite long, and the drawer jumps out much wider. 
I would like the drawer to have a width that is 30% of the window size, but when I try to set the classes on the drawer, neither root nor modal classNames seem to hold the drawer width in place.

This is the Drawer code:

```
<Drawer classes={drawerClasses} open={showStandardDrawer} anchor={"right"} onClose={closeDrawer}>

 {Array.from(items).map((item, index) => {
      return (
      <List
          key={`list-${index}`}
          component="div"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          subheader={
             <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
                 {item.title}
             </ListSubheader>
          }
          className={classes.root}
      >
         { item.elements.map((el, index) => {
             return (
              <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <ListItem key={index} button onClick={() => handleExpand(index)}>
                     <ListItemText primary={el.name} />
                          {open[index] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                  </ListItem>
                  <Collapse in={open[index]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                      { el.descriptions.map((description, index) => {
                           return (
                               <List key={`l-${index}`} component="div" disablePadding>
                                 <ListItem button className={classes.nested} >
                                     <ListItemIcon>
                                        <StarBorder />
                                     </ListItemIcon>
                                     <ListItemText primary={description} primaryTypographyProps={{noWrap:true, width:'200px'} } />
                                   </ListItem>
                                </List>
                          )})
                    }
                    </Collapse>
               </React.Fragment>
            )
       })}
     </List>
    )
    })}
</Drawer>
```

and these are the classes applied to the drawer ('drawerClasses'):

```
{
    root: {
        maxWidth: '200px',
        minWidth: '50%',
        width: '50%',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    modal: {
        maxWidth: '50%',
        minWidth: '50%',
        width: '50%'
    }
}
```

These aren't the styles I necessarily want, I'm just trying to see if I can get Drawer to size itself instead of sizing around its children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `modal`, use the `paper` class. The `Paper` element within the drawer is the main visible container. The `root` and `modal` classes are applied to wrapper elements that are positioned in such a manner that their widths won't necessarily affect the Paper width.

Here's a code excerpt from the [Permanent drawer demo](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#permanent-drawer):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
}));

...

      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
        anchor="left"
      >
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zxljh

Comment: Thanks for your response... I don't want a permanent drawer.  I want one that opens and closes on demand.  The drawerPaper also had no effect.  I'm going to try creating a Typography element with a width to tame the size of the ListItemText.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to your question that reproduces your specific scenario/issue. Though to clarify, you should have used a class key of "paper" not "drawerPaper". Your comment makes it sound like you used "drawerPaper".

Comment: The problem was that I had not set className on the Drawer, only the classes.  So, now it works, but I don't like how it behaves, so I'm going to leave it and think about how to improve the visibility of the descriptions within each collapsible list.